# AngularJS edit record behaviour not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

My page has a form to add objects to an array. The array is displayed on the page with links to edit the array item.

When I add items I attach a primary key to be able to edit that item later in case it is deleted and its array index is changed.

The add functionality is working but the edit behavior is not. When I update the ng-model to which the form controls are bound the form does not display the record to be edited. It might be a $scope issue but I declared the model in the parent $scope specifically to achieve this.

Here is a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yDlPpFunxFLHPiI0kCdj?p=preview

```
<form ng-controller="formCtrl" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="student.name" placeholder="name">
  <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="student.age" placeholder="age">
  <input type="hidden" ng-value="pk">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<h1>students</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in students"><a href="#" ng-click="editStudent(item.pk)">{{item.name}}</a> - {{item.age}}</li>
</ul>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope',  function($scope ){

    $scope.student = {};
    $scope.pk = 1;
    $scope.index = 0;
    $scope.students = [];

    $scope.editStudent = function (id) {


        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.students.length; i++) {
            console.log("comparing "+$scope.students[i].pk+ " & " + id);
            if ($scope.students[i].pk == id ) {
                console.log("editing pk nr.: "+ id);
                $scope.student = {
                    name: $scope.students[i].name,
                    age: $scope.students[i].age
                };
                $scope.index = id;
            }
        }


    };


}]);



myApp.controller("formCtrl",  ['$scope',  function($scope) {

    $scope.submit = function () {

        if ($scope.index === 0) {
            $scope.students.push({
                name: $scope.student.name,
                age: $scope.student.age,
                pk: $scope.pk
            });

            $scope.pk++;
            $scope.student = {};
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.students.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.students[i].pk == $scope.index) {
                    $scope.students[i] = {
                        name: $scope.student.name,
                        age: $scope.student.age,
                        pk: $scope.index
                    };
                }
            }

            $scope.index = 0;
        }
    };


}]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey yes you are doing it in a wrong way you need to create a sevice to share data between controllers.

Comment: It's indeed a scoping issue, you use two different controller which each spawn their own `$scope`

Comment: but the child view (the form) is bound to elements in the parent controller and it is working with the insert. why is it not working the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yDlPpFunxFLHPiI0kCdj?p=preview), see the changes [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BLH6QHVovXa2HINFcSpZ?p=preview).

The changes i made were:

- Removed the form controller, no need for 2 controllers in your app.
- Used the `$index` property that is available when using `ng-repeat` to edit the item you click.

Here is your `HTML`:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ct">

    <form novalidate>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newStudent.name" placeholder="name">
      <input type="number" name="age" ng-model="newStudent.age" placeholder="age">
      <input type="hidden" ng-value="pk">
      <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="submit()">
    </form>

    <h1>students</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in students"><a href="#" ng-click="editStudent($index)">{{item.name}}</a> - {{item.age}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And your `JavaScript` File:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope',  function($scope ){

    $scope.newStudent = {};
    $scope.students = [];

    $scope.index = -1;

    $scope.editStudent = function (index) {
      console.log('Editing student: ' + $scope.students[index].name);
      $scope.index = index;
      $scope.newStudent = angular.copy($scope.students[index]);
    };  


    $scope.submit = function () {
      if ($scope.index < 0) {
        $scope.students.push($scope.newStudent);
      } else {
        $scope.students[$scope.index] = $scope.newStudent;
      }

      $scope.newStudent = {
        name: '',
        age: ''
      }

      $scope.index = -1;
    };

}]);
```

**Edit:**
I just modified the code for when editing the student, to use `angular.copy` so that when you are editing, it loses the binding to the `$scope.students` array, and the changes are only applied when you click on the submit button.

Comment: using $index in functions is bad - once u want to add orderBy in html, u'll need rewrite everything

Comment: I just made the changes for the functionality that the OP wants, trying to use the same logic he was using. I'm aware of that. Thanks for the tip though @PetrAveryanov .

Comment: ok. your code is better :) but why wasn't my code working? why could i use the parent scope for submitting but not for editing ?

Comment: @Patriot Your code wasn't working because everytime you use the `ng-controller`, it creates a new `scope` inside the parent `scope`, and to communicate between them you needed to use the `$scope.$parent`, or `$scope.$emit` / `$scope.$broadcast` to emit events and then you ran some code using `$scope.$on` to catch the event. But navigating between scopes is part of the bad practices in AngularJs. And the events is just for when you want to run some code that depends on some action from another controller.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the edit. the initial binding was a little bit distracting.